# Authenticating Internal / External Users w/ MOSS 2007 & ISA 2006

Tags: sharepoint, isa-server

I'm looking for a solution to be able to authenticate internal and external users to MOSS 2007 using different authentication methods, but the same URL.  Here's the scenario:

Internal Users: Authenticate using RSA SecureID w/ AD #1

External Users: Authenticate using PKI w/ AD #2

I've seen plenty of solutions to accomplish this using two separate URLs, such as this one:
http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2006/08/16/configuring-multiple-authentication-providers-for-sharepoint-2007.aspx

However, using ISA 2006, I'd like to get this set up with one URL and have the ISA manage which SharePoint site requests get sent to based on if they're already authenticated and if not, whether they specify themselves as an internal or external user.

This seems like it should be possible, but I haven't found a way to do it yet.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do local users have to go through the ISA Server to access de MOSS server?

Answer (score 1):

When you publish websites in ISA you have the choice of choosing which network/users to publish the site to. So what you would need to do is to publish the sharepoint site two times. One time to the internal users on your private network and another time to the external users.

I have not done this so this is more of a suggestion to look into.